# Multiple interface: instanceof cannot differentiate different interfaces

Tags: java

If I have the following:

```
interface a {
    void a_m();
}

interface b {
    void b_m();
}

class x implements a, b {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
         x cx = new x();
         System.out.println(cx instanceof a); <-- true
         System.out.println(cx instanceof b); <-- true
    }

    void a_m() {}
    void b_m() {}

}
```

The `instanceof` operator will return true for both.

Of course I know that `getClass()` will do the trick but I'm just puzzled of the usage of `instanceof` here.

In the above case, interfaces a and b are different and there must be a way which tells them apart (as far as class x is concerned).

Any advice would be great

Comment: What is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: there is no usage of instanceof ere

Comment: Why do you expect anything else?  Where in Java specs/docs have you seen anything different?

Comment: There is no *super interface* here. You simply have a class that implements multiple interfaces.

Comment: What do you mean by _tell them apart_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What's the points for class x having 2 different interfaces if those interfaces are not different? Might as well have 1 interface. Class x implements both interfaces a and b and those interfaces have different methods to be implemented. If i have an instance of class x, how do i check if that object is interface a or b, bearing in mind those 2 interfaces are distinct and different?

Comment: `cx instanceof a` tells you if `cx` implements `a`. `cx instanceof b` tells you if `cx` implements `b`. I still don't see the issue. Those are two distinct interfaces.

Comment: @yapkm01 If it's both, then it has *both* interface methods. You could also use reflection to check if a class has a method (regardless of interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` just checks whether you are actually an instance of something. In other words whether you could be legally assigned/cast/etc to be of that type.

In this case X implements both A and B so it is indeed an instance of both. If you wanted to check for an X then you would do `instanceof X`, not `instanceof A` and `instanceof B`.

There is no "telling apart" involved though. X is an X, you can also use it as either an A or a B if you want to but there is only one object. When you create an X every single X *must* be usable as an A, a B and an X. That's what implementing an interface means.

Imagine X is a house. All A says is "X must have a front door", B says "X must have a back door". If Y implements A but not B then:

```
 X instanceof A == X has a front door == true
 X instanceof B == X has a back door == true
 Y instanceof A == Y has a front door == true
 Y instanceof B == Y has a back door == false
```

Comment: You said 'there is no telling apart'. A = front door. B=back door. If there's not telling apart for class X, i might as well have 1 interface which says front door & back door.

Comment: But then you couldn't create class Y which only has a front door...

Comment: @yapkm01 You could also make an interface as `interface C extends A, B {}` and have your class implement that.

Comment: @TimB I see the light! Thanks.